# Flask пререндр базового шаблона?

Tags: flask, jinja2

Всем привет, ситуация следующая.
Есть базовый шаблон в котором определена шапка, в этой шапке есть поле уведомлений *notifications bar.
Суть моей задачи заключается в том, что бы базовый шаблон получал данные из бд не через тот шаблон который его наследует, а непосредственно сам, то есть своеобразий пререндр.
Я знаком с принципом работы {{ super }} но в таком случае мне нужно будет передавать состояние всякий раз при рендре любой страницы которая расширяет базовый шаблон, по моему это нарушает концепцию

> don't repeat yourself

В связи с этим у меня вопрос: как я могу один раз объявив данные для базового шаблона, вызывать их при раендре из другого шаблона? Я например вижу такую реализацию. Создать функцию которая получает свежие данные из бд, и привязать её к базовому шаблону. Всякий раз при отрисовки расширяемого шаблона, эта функция будет обновлять состояние базового шаблона, следовательно и нужно мне странице тоже.
Если я что-то не так понимаю, или делаю, то пожалуйста подскажите, я с радостью использую ваш вариант вместо этого. Просто я совсем не понимаю как это реализовать, правильным образом!
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно Вам подойдет `context processor`.
Пример:

```
from flask import Blueprint

from utils import db_connect

app = Blueprint("name", __name__, template_folder='templates')

@app.route("/")
def index():
  return render_template("index.html")

@app.context_processor
def any_data_processor():
  with db_connect.connect() as con: 
# тут же могла быть работа с кэшем/API/файловой системой и др.
    ....
  result = ...
  return dict(any_data=result)
```

После этого обращаться внутри всех шаблонов можно без явной передачи туда контекста.

```
<h1> {{ any_data }}</h1>
```

Аналогично можно написать функцию, которую можн вызывать внутри шаблона с аргументами.

Но, вообще говоря, не вижу проблемы в явной передаче контекста родительского шаблона - дочернему)